# Is there a way to use a service to lower your latency?

Tags: networking, internet, ping, latency

There is this service [wtfast](http://www.google.com.br/#q=wtfast) that claims it can lower your ping in some games. Is this true? How it works?

Comment: I doubt that's possible..

Comment: Sure, if the service lets you break that pesky "speed of light" limit.

Comment: The only way a VPN can lower your latency to some server is if your ISP has a more direct link that is only configured with a limited set of prefixes which includes the VPN endpoint, and the VPN endpoint is close enough to the server that you<->endpoint + endpoint<->server is less than you<->server. So basically you're depending on your ISP to have a backup link configured exactly for your needs and that they will never change that setup. Good luck.

Comment: @micmcg lol nice joke. Of course this is possible, e.g. the service could put a long wire between you and the servers. Often ISP routes are inefficient af.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most services that claim to reduce your latency does so through providing a VPN or tunneling service, which routes the path packets take between you and the game server over a supposedly more efficient and shorter route. It also has the advantage of bypassing ISP filters and throttling.

This might sound good on paper, but in practice, it often doesn't live up to expectations. Even though the connection between the service and the game server might be good, it doesn't mean that connection between you and the service is. The service itself also introduces another layer in the network, which might just end up adding more latency to the connection.

Furthermore, shady providers might be sniffing and eavesdropping on your data, since now your connection runs through their servers.

All in all, not a good thing, and I'd advise against.